# im to Iterate through Object by transforming it into an array with Angular5. newbie

Tags: javascript, angular5

The data coming from console log is displayed like this

```js
{
  todos: Array(2)
}
todos: (2)[{…}, {…}] __proto__:
  Object
```

this data is from a Service

```js
@Injectable()

export class BeerServiceService {

  beerUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/todos';
  beers: Observable < ManageBeer[] > ;

  beer = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  addBeer(beer: ManageBeer): Observable < ManageBeer > {
    return this.http.post < ManageBeer > (this.beerUrl, beer);
  }
  getBeers(): Observable < ManageBeer[] > {
    return this.beers = this.http.get < ManageBeer[] > (this.beerUrl);
  }

}
```

i'm trying to convert Object into an array so i can be able to iterate through here's code below.

```js
export class ManagerBeersComponent implements OnInit {


  result = [];

  constructor(private beerSer: BeerServiceService) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.beerSer.getBeers().subscribe(beer => {
      this.result = beer;
      console.log(this.result);
    });
  }
}
```

resuERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed at lt comes back as an object and im getting this error.

Comment: from where do you get this data? I mean from server mongodb or something?

Comment: Please, revise your question and make it clearer. There are a lot of mistakes and the information about the error is malformed, incomplete and impossible to understand. Besides, where are you getting this error?

Comment: sorry i coudnt explain it in a better way. but i got a solution

Comment: @muzijack I see you unmarked my answer . Was the solution something different?

Comment: @gawicks sorry for that i've double tapped on mark by mistake your solution helped me. i've marked you.

Comment: @muzijack .ok thanks for confirming the answer.

Comment: @gawicks do you know any sources where i can learn JavaScript, for example the solution u provided where can i find docs like that?

Comment: @muzijack That's actually typescript not javascript. I don't know any specific sources but its pretty easy to find . I usually go for youtube tutorials.

Comment: i can't seem to bind id {{beer.id}} or {{beer.$id}} from this  what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear. But I assume you're trying to *ngFor over that object which is causing the error. Try assigning the *array* to `this.result` instead.

```
this.beerSer.getBeers().subscribe(beer => {
  this.result = (beer as any).todos;
  console.log(this.result);
});
```